# Chrome USB API no listInterfaces method

Tags: usb, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to use USB api on Google Chrome v.28.0.1500.71/MacOSX 10.8.4. FindDevices method finds my device (USB CCID-class) but when executing chrome.usb.listInterfaces(device,callback) I get error

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'listInterfaces'.
Code see below:

```
chrome.usb.findDevices( DEVICE_INFO, 
  function(devices) {
    if (!devices || !devices.length) {
      console.log('device not found');
      return;
    }
    console.log('Found device: ' + devices[0].handle);
    console.log(devices[0]);
    powerMateDevice = devices[0];

    console.log('listing ifcs...'); 
    chrome.usb.listInterfaces(powerMateDevice, function(ifcs){
        console.log('interfaces '+ifcs.length);
        console.log(ifcs);
    }); 

});
```

My question is, Am I using this API in wrong way or listInterfaces is not yet implemented as described in http://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listInterfaces method was added on [May 28, 2013](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/api/usb.idl?revision=202097). That's after the May 6 [branch point](http://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar) for Chrome 28. Try the dev channel instead. If you'd like to file a bug report for the documentation issue, you may do so at crbug.com.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, now I am using dev channel and listInterfaces works great. Looking forward for comming to stable version.